# Node.js express and postgress sql pool.query

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, web-applications

I am having problem to add result of pool.query to variable (With pool.query I am selecting only one value, id value, that I need to insert into other table). So far I have this but console.log gives me

> Promise { < pending > }

```
router.get("/restaurants/add",checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {

    var  x = pool.query(`select delivery.id from delivery order by id desc limit 1`);
    console.log(x);


    /*pool.query(
        `INSERT INTO new_table (newId)
                    VALUES ($1)`,
        [x]);*/
    res.redirect("/restaurants/dashboard")
});
```

Any help would be of great value.

Comment: Looks like you lack await so the promise is not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use `insert into .. select ..` as follows:

```
Insert into new_table (column_name)
select delivery.id from delivery order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: Yea, that is a great way to do it, but now I have problem because I need to add one more column into same table with value req.user.id